# How do I add an option to quote blocks to preserve newlines?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, quote

Some blocks such as `begin_verse` or `begin_example` preserve newlines. But the `begin_quote` block does not and we need two new lines to create a new line in the exported HTML.

What's the best way to have a quote block that preserves new lines? Should I add a new block with a new name, or can I add a heading argument to `quote` blocks?

---

My ideal solution would look like this:

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE :preserve-whitespace true
1
2
3
#+END_QUOTE
```

Which exports as three lines in a quote block.

Comment: Why not use a verse block? That's precisely why they exist: to enforce linebreaks/

Comment: @NickD The verse blocks don't actually export as quotes though?

Comment: With the default CSS, there is no difference that I can see: quotes are surrounded by `<blockquote>` tags, whereas verses are paragraphs of class `verse`. I presume you can make either one look any way you want by changing the CSS, but what exactly do you want them to look like?

Comment: @NickD Thanks, I'll customize the CSS then. Is there a way to add more CSS classes to a block? E.g., suppose I want some verse blocks to have a red background, but not the others. Sth like [this](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-special-blocks.html), but these special blocks don't let me control the whitespace preservation.